# Shell script to startup, exit and run other scripts once it completes

Tags: database, oracle, shell, automation

I have been trying to automate this process in shell script in a unix box. I am new to shell scripts. 
I have not been able to figure out how to detect when the startup for it has finished . Also, how to 
create a new terminal and check the domain.log for the new terminal. I would appreciate if anyone
can help me on this .

```
cd $/home/oracle/12/bin 
./lsnrctl start
```

Login to `sqlplus` with username `sys as sysdba` and password: `oracle3211` 
and run the database startup command `startup`

Once it is started type `exit`

--now start the dbconsole

```
cd $/home/oracle/12/bin 
./emctl start dbconsole
```

--open a new terminal and execute this

```
$/home/oracle/startWeblogic.sh
```

--wait for domain.log keyword in the log file to confirm the server has started
--if the server is started proceed to the following in a new terminal

```
$/home/oracle/startManagedWeblogic.sh
```

--after this access the following urls

```
https://178:198:29:28:1167/em (username=system1, password=oracle123)
https://178:198:29:28:1176/em (username=system2, password=oracle132)
```

Comment: If you are looking for a way to automate the processes and also sending key strokes (such as "exit"). Look for a command-line tool called `expect`. There are several good examples, if you googled for it.

Comment: Did you try searching here on S.O.? I know I have seen numerous messages about automating access to Oracle. Good Luck.

Comment: @Har Vu: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you also need to learn about the GNU `screen` command. You may already have it installed. Try `screen -R -D`

If it gives you a shell prompt at the top of the screen then it works. Now if you disconnect your ssh session or close your terminal window (click on the X), the next time you log in and run the exact same screen command, you are reconnected to the same running terminal session.

This allows you to run scripts, etc. which do not stop when you disconnect. And when you reconnect you can see their current output.

Also, you can have many terminal sessions. `Ctrl-A c` creates another one. `Ctrl-A [space]` and `Ctrl-A [backspace]` rotate between sessions in the list. `Ctrl-A ?` gives you all the other Ctrl-A commands that you can use. For instance, one session could be `tail logfile` while another one is running a program waiting for input.